# I want to print how many number is greater than the average

Tags: java

I already print the total and average. However I can't print how many numbers is greater than average.

I think the problem is the `number>= average`, it seems like only adding the last input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int number = 0;
        double total=0;
        double average=0;
        int aboveaverage=0;
        Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);

        for(i=1;i<9;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter number " + i +": ");
            number=read.nextInt();
            if(number<0){
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                break;
            }

            total+=number; 
        } 
        if(number>=average){
            aboveaverage+=1;
            System.out.println("Greater than average is :" + aboveaverage);
        }
        average=total/8;   
        System.out.println("Print total : "+ total);
        System.out.println("Print Average : " +average ); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: You have to collect all the numbers in a `List<Integer>` so you can scan them again, once you know what the average is. Or, since you know how many numbers you'll have, you can use an `int[]`.

Comment: @Andreas There's no need of a `List` if the number of elements is already known.

Comment: @MaximeLaunois Yeah, I just realized that too, so enhanced comment to say that. :-)

Comment: Is there any solution except array? I also think that maybe array is more easy to do?

Comment: @Andreas You're right obviously, it's early and I haven't had coffee yet, apologies. Disregard my answer if you read it OP.

Comment: @zerofour You have to save the values, somehow, so you can scan them again, once you've calculated `average`. An array is the best choice for that, but requires that you know how many numbers you'll get. If you didn't know up front how many numbers you'd get, a `List` would be the best choice.

Comment: okay get it  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to collect all numbers (by placing them in an `int` array), and iterate over all numbers, for example inside a **for** loop.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int number = 0;
        int numberCount = 8;
        int[] numberArray = new int[numberCount];
        double total = 0;
        double average = 0;
        int aboveAverage = 0;
        Scanner read = new Scanner (System.in);

        for(i = 0; i < numberCount; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            number = read.nextInt();
            if(number < 0){
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                continue;
            }

            numberArray[i] = number;
            total += number;
        }
        average = total / numberCount;

        for(i = 0; i < numberCount; i++){
            if(numberArray[i] > average) {
                aboveAverage++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Count of numbers greater than average: " + aboveAverage);
        System.out.println("Print total: " + total);
        System.out.println("Print average: " + average);
}
```